# SQL AlwaysOn for application running on workgroup servers

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups

I'm running a SQL 2012R2 with AlwaysOn setup in an isolated cloud environment. We have 2 VMs running AD and 2 VMs running SQL 2012R2 with AlwaysOn configured. All these have been configured and works perfectly fine.

My problem is that the application servers in this environment (web, app and etc) are all non-domain servers(workgroup). Because of this, they are unable to resolve the active IP address of the AlwaysOn AG listener's FQDN. Instead, they can only connect to the database via the physical IP of the SQL server.

My question is, is it possible to configure the workgroup computers to some how use the DNS service provided by AD so that they can then resolve the IP of the AG Listener and yet remain as a workgroup computer?

Comment: You can go to the network adaptors and configure their DNS server(s). https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816762(v=ws.10).aspx